how to put a Gltf Model in a group
I'm trying to put a loaded gltf model in a group with a cube.
I have tried doing it normally, but the sword model doesn't move. I am fairly new to three.js as I am in 7th grade doing this on my own time. I spent a great time off of this game I am making because I had a great setback with the models. My Chromebook is weird because of the school restrictions so I have to run the script on replit.
before Z: 
After Z:


const player = new THREE.Group();
    if(sword) player.add(sword);// sword is the gltf.scene
     player.add(cube2)



here is the link to the project
How would I do it?
here is more of the script


    let robot;
    let sword;
    let swordd;

    loader.load( 'RobotExpressive.glb', function ( gltf )
        {
          robot = gltf.scene;  // sword 3D object is loaded
          robot.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
          scene.add(robot);
        } );
    loader.load( 'Sword.glb', function ( gltf )
    {
      sword = gltf.scene;  // sword 3D object is loaded
      sword.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
      scene.add(sword);
      swordd = gltf.asset;
    } );
    const robotBody = new createCannonBox(
         new CANNON.Vec3(1,1,1),
         new CANNON.Vec3(5, 5, 5),
         10
       ); 
     // Initlising the modles ^
     
     
     const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
          cube2.castShadow = true;
          scene.add(cube2);
          const cubeBody2 = new createCannonBall(1, new CANNON.Vec3(0, 2, 0), 1);
    // makeing cube using custom funtion ^
const group = new THREE.Group()
group.add( sword );
group.add( cube2 );

// Do not forget this line
scene.add( group );
// making the group^

    function go() {
            if (keys.w) moveVector.z -= 0.1;
            if (keys.s) moveVector.z += 0.1;
            if (keys.a) moveVector.x -= 0.1;
            if (keys.d) moveVector.x += 0.1;
            if (keys.c) moveVector.y -= 0.1;
            if (keys.v) moveVector.y += 0.1;
            if (checkK && colide && keys.b) (checkK = false), (colide = false);
            if (!checkK && keys.b)
              (boddy.mass = 1), Name.scale.copy(new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1));
            if (keys.m) controls.lock();
            if (keys.p) cubeBody.velocity.set(0, 0, 0), ballBody.velocity.set(0, 0, 0);
            window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
              if (e.code == "Space" && g == true)
                cubeBody2.velocity.set(0, 5, 0), (g = false);
            });

            move(cube1);
            move(ball1);
            
            
            if (robot) robot.position.copy(robotBody.position);
            if (robot) robot.quaternion.copy(robotBody.quaternion);
           // if (sword) sword.position.copy(swordBody.position);
            //if (sword) //sword.quaternion.copy(swordBody.quaternion);

            
            
            

            moveVector.multiplyScalar(0.6);
            camera.translateX(moveVector.x);
            camera.translateZ(moveVector.z);
            camera.translateY(moveVector.y);

            if (colide && checkK) {
              Name.scale.copy(new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
              if (keys.c) distance += 0.1;
              if (keys.v && distance > 1) distance -= 0.1;
              boddy.quaternion.copy(camera.quaternion);
              Name.position.copy(camera.position);
              Name.translateX(moveVector.x);
              Name.translateY(moveVector.y);
              Name.translateZ(moveVector.z - distance);
              boddy.position.copy(Name.position);
            
            } else {
              pickup = true;
            }
            
           

            
            score.innerText = checkK;
            cube.position.copy(cubeBody.position);
            cube.quaternion.copy(cubeBody.quaternion);
            ball.position.copy(ballBody.position);
            ball.quaternion.copy(ballBody.quaternion);
            camera.position.y = cubeBody2.position.y;
            cubeBody2.position.x = camera.position.x;
            cubeBody2.position.z = camera.position.z;
            cubeBody2.quaternion.copy(camera.quaternion);
            if (sword && keys.z)  group.position.y = 2;
            
            if (clock.elapsedTime - lastResetTime >= resetInterval) {
              lastResetTime = clock.elapsedTime;
            }
          }

          function animate() {
            const delta = clock.getDelta();
            world.step(delta);
            check();
            go();
            fly.update(delta);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
          }

          animate();
          
       // update and animate script^




Well, you already have the correct answer.
To add two objects into a group, you need to use the .add() method like this:


const group = new THREE.Group()
group.add( sword );
group.add( cube2 );

// Do not forget this line
scene.add( group );



Do not forget to add the group to the scene.

Edit since code is shared
I tried your code and it's working as it should be. I didn't downloaded your gltf files so I added a capsule instead of the sword.
You have your group with the sword (here the green capsule) and the cube. With your code, when you press Z, the group should go up as follow:
if (sword && keys.z)  group.position.y = 2;

This is before pressing the Z key:

After pressing Z;

So, what's the issue here? I don't see any.

i did that but the sword doesn't move with the cube

Could you show a bit more of your code please? Like how you move the object, etc. Do you move the group or the cube or the sword?

I added a link to the project, currently I am just setting the group's position for a test, I plan to make it the player model so that the player can hold the sword.

In the code you shared, you don't use the group. You create it, add it to the scene and that's it.
Is there some code missing? I don't even see an update loop and there is a bracket missing at the end so I guess you didn't put it there

that is so weird, i will add the more of script

i added some pictures

Idk why its not working

just had to put it in the update function lol, thank you so much for your help!
